# change image of list on list click android:

Tags: android

I have a ListView of 5 rows and each rows have different images. When I click on listview at any position then ListView image on that row changes only and each row have diffrent image on list.

I have ListView items containing ImageView and TextView in each rows and by default in each row I show image corresponding to text in row and when I click on any position of list then I want to change the image corresponding to list click position. I have to show two different image on list click.

In a list there are 2 images one is for event "off" and second image is for "on".

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) { 
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected"
                    +(position+1)+"th item",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}![enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi saurabh trivedi, your question / problem is not so clear, please rephrase.

Comment: hi,please try the custom toggle btn or u can make two image view with overlap and make the hide/show on click

Comment: i addead my screen shot what i want ...

Answer (score 0):

There is two approaches to achieve the same

**First Approach**
Set the background of the list item to a **State List drawable**. If you set this on every item, the state list will automatically mantain the state.

**Second Approach**

```
Use HashMap to store which item the user has selected and set background depending on the user selection
Example

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomListView extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Context context = null;
    HashMap<String, Boolean> userSelectionMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PENS);
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        this.registerForContextMenu(lv);




    }



    static final String[] PENS = new String[]{

        "item1",
        "item2",
        "item3",
        "item4",
        "item5",
        "item6",




    };

   @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    System.out.println("...selected...");
    if(isItemSelectedBefore(""+position)){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whbk);
    }else{
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grbk);
    }
}

  boolean isItemSelectedBefore(String position){
      boolean userSelection = false;
      if(userSelectionMap.containsKey(position)){
          userSelection = !userSelection;
      }
      userSelectionMap.put(position, userSelection);
    return userSelectionMap.get(position);

   }

}
```

### To change backgorunf of list view

create a selector like the following **list_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/android_green" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/black_alpha" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/black_alpha" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white_alpha" />
</selector>
```

**xml of listview**

Comment: hi deepakkk ...when i change the selection of position in list thenit retains its previous image means "offadd.png" and when again select "onadd.png"

Comment: can you explain me what you want?

Comment: deepakkk this is my application screen shot what i want to achive ..white background means list is selected and when i change the list position then it will become blue and selected background will be white url is pls click on it   http://skitch.com/saurabh26213/fmuq4/mainmenu